# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax. line 1

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

I just finished installing MySQL 8.0.35 and Python 3.12.0. I added the path to my environment variables. But in my command prompt, I keep getting this error message.

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
> Your MySQL connection id is 12
> Server version: 8.0.35 MySQL Community Server - GPL
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
> affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
> owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> mysql> show database;
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database' at line 1
> mysql>

Comment: Did you try doing what the message said, and check the documentation? You can find it easily by using your favorite search engine and searching for *mysql documentation* and then clicking the link for the version you're using. Your **first** reference (long before posting here) should be reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's `SHOW DATABASES` or `SHOW SCHEMAS`.

You need the S on the end.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html